# Javascript zoom in/out in overlay not working on second image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some javascript that calls for an overlay to display a full preview of images, and a button to zoom-in/out and a button to go back.

The trouble is when I first view the full image, the zoom in/out toggle works fine, but when I go back to the thumbnails and launch another image, the zoom-in/out does not work.

The DOM tree structure is like this:
`overlay(**parent**) >> imgContainer >> imgCanvas(draggable) >> img`

May be some code would help my case. Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong here?

```
//enables the zoom-in/zoom-out toggle function
        $('#Zoom').toggle(function() {
                img.removeAttribute("height");
                $("#draggable").draggable();                
                iconZ.setAttribute("src", "nav/nav-zoom-out.gif");
            },              
            function() {
                img.setAttribute("height", "270px");
                $("#draggable").draggable('destroy');
                $("#draggable").animate(
                { "left": $("#draggable").data("Left"), "top": $("#draggable").data("Top")}, "slow");
                iconZ.setAttribute("src", "nav/nav-zoom.gif");
                });

        //navigates back to the thumbnails
        home.addEventListener('click', function() {


            $('imgCanvas').remove();
            imgContainer.removeChild(imgCanvas);
            overlay.removeChild(imgContainer);

            $('#overlay').removeClass("on");
            }
            , false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying what looks like the sections of the page you are putting the images in.  I think you mean to hide them only.